# Botão 'copiar texto' em C#

Tags: c#, button

Sou novato em `C#`, e queria criar um botão que ao ser clicado, ele copiará o texto descrito nesse mesmo botão.

Se não me fiz entender, imagine que o **botão** tem um texto inserido nele (por ex: <kbd>Csharp</kbd>), quando você clicar nesse botão, o conteudo `Csharp` será copiado. Em seguida você pode ir e abrir por exemplo o Bloco de Notas e dar um colar, e o texto `Csharp` será colado.

Alguém me pode ajudar a criar isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [*Clipboard*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void BtnCsharp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetText(((Button)sender).Text);
    //ou
    //Clipboard.SetText(BtnCsharp.Text);
}
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se for um ***contéudo*** fixo na sua aplicação crie uma variável `string texto` e cole o texto dentro dele dessa forma:

```
private void BtnTomcat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string texto = "StackOverFlow StackOverFlow StackOver";            
    Clipboard.SetText(texto);
}
```

Para mudar o Texto do Botão, vai na caixa de propriedades e coloque em **Text** o nome que preferir.

Comment: Cezar , bom dia !  agradeço infinitamente sua ajuda !!!!
O unico problema que não saquei direito onde colocar o texto, minhas disculpas mais eu sou leigo demais, acabei de baixar o Visual Studio 2010.
O conteudo que eu preciso que tenha o texto é de umas 40 linhas , poi é uma configuração de um servidor .
Pode me continuar ajudando onde posso colocar esse texto?
Obrigado !!!

Comment: Me detalhe (sem cortar nada) o que realmente quer fazer ???

Comment: Cezar, obrigado por responder !
O botão se chamara Tomcat , e ao clicar nele ira copiar a configuração de um servidor , o conteudo de esse texto tem aproximadamente 40 linhas a 80 linhas.

Tipo seu exemplo esta perfeito , somente que ao invez do seu botão que se chama Csharp , será Tomcat , e o texto será bem grande ( 40 a 80 linhas ) ao invez de Csharp qual você colou no bloco de notas , me entende?
Onde eu coloco meu texto ? ao invez da palavra Csharp ( substituir por 40 a 80 linhas ).
Obrigado !!!

Comment: Você pode colocar em uma variável, sem problemas. Da onde vem seu texto ? ele vai ficar dentro da aplicação ?

Comment: Sim , o texto ficará dentro da aplicação .
O texto eu já tenho ele , são 40 a 80 linhas .
Pode me ajudar nisso, por favor?
Obrigado.

Comment: Já coloquei um adendo na resposta siga e com certeza conseguirá a fazer o sua app.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30112/discussion-between-cezar-and-rodrigo-hackz-exploitz).